# take out text before a number in an ID

Tags: jquery

I have a click function that grabs the #id of a DIV

all the DIV's have id's like this:

bar01
bar02
bar03
bar04

I just need the 01, 02, 03...

So i need to remove the 'bar' from the #id to pass it into my function

```
$(".day div").click(function(){
    var idNum = $(this).attr("id");
    LoadTopTenBar(idNum);
});
```

the remove(), doesn't seem to be what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var idNum = $(this).attr("id").replace('bar','');
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you actually want to parse the digits into a javascript number, you can do it like this:

```
$(".day div").click(function(){
    var idNum = +this.id.replace(/\D/g, "");
    LoadTopTenBar(idNum);
});
```

This removes all non-digits from the string, then converts the remaining characters to a number.  Note, there is no need to use jQuery to get the id value as it just adds extra code.

If you just wanted the digits as a string, leave out the `+` sign.

Comment: @dfsq - Thx. I added the `g` flag which is how I meant it to work originally.

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
$(".day div").click(function(){
    var idNum = $(this).attr("id");
    idNum = idNum.replace("bar", "");
    LoadTopTenBar(idNum);
});
```